# Is there a way in r to check if each date of a list of dates is within a list of intervals?

Tags: r, time-series, lubridate, quantmod

I have a time series for a certain stock ticker. I also have a dataframe with 2 columns representing start and end dates of recessions.
I need to create a list that represents whether each day of the stock time series was in recession (1) or not (0).
So to be more detailed, my table looks like this:

```
    structure(list(Peak = structure(c(-20819, -18781, -18263, -17047, 
-15798, -14763, -11933, -9100, -7731, -6028, -4536, -3562, -31, 
1400, 3652, 4199, 7486, 11382, 13848, 18293), class = "Date"), 
    Trough = structure(c(-20120, -18569, -17716, -16620, -15402, 
    -13455, -11537, -8858, -7397, -5724, -4293, -3256, 304, 1885, 
    3834, 4687, 7729, 11627, 14396, 18504), class = "Date")), row.names = 4:23, class = "data.frame")
```

and I tried:

```
getSymbols('NFCI', src = 'FRED')
time(NFCI) %within% interval(recessions$Peak,recessions$Trough)
```

but I don't get a correct answer, and I also get a warning

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I could do a loop and check each row, but thought there might be an easier way.
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Apparently, I did get the correct answer, but I manually tested it incorrectly, that's why I thought the answer was wrong. Thanks to @FernandoBarbosa and @RuiBarradas for making me notice it.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data.

Comment: I hope this is more helpful

Comment: It is not, because it is not reproducible. See ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's better but image files are not a good way of posting data (or code). [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(tail(recessions, 20))`.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas , I didn't know about the dput() function. I hope this is better.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to coerce the `interval` object to class `"list"`. See the last example in [``` help(``%within%``) ```](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.9/topics/%25within%25).

```
library(lubridate)
library(quantmod)

aapl <- getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign = FALSE)

time(aapl) %within% as.list(interval(recessions$Peak, recessions$Trough))
```

---

*This edit is meant to answer the comments below.*

The output of the `interval` call is

```
interval(recessions$Peak, recessions$Trough)
# [1] 1913-01-01 UTC--1914-12-01 UTC 1918-08-01 UTC--1919-03-01 UTC
# [3] 1920-01-01 UTC--1921-07-01 UTC 1923-05-01 UTC--1924-07-01 UTC
# [5] 1926-10-01 UTC--1927-11-01 UTC 1929-08-01 UTC--1933-03-01 UTC
# [7] 1937-05-01 UTC--1938-06-01 UTC 1945-02-01 UTC--1945-10-01 UTC
# [9] 1948-11-01 UTC--1949-10-01 UTC 1953-07-01 UTC--1954-05-01 UTC
#[11] 1957-08-01 UTC--1958-04-01 UTC 1960-04-01 UTC--1961-02-01 UTC
#[13] 1969-12-01 UTC--1970-11-01 UTC 1973-11-01 UTC--1975-03-01 UTC
#[15] 1980-01-01 UTC--1980-07-01 UTC 1981-07-01 UTC--1982-11-01 UTC
#[17] 1990-07-01 UTC--1991-03-01 UTC 2001-03-01 UTC--2001-11-01 UTC
#[19] 2007-12-01 UTC--2009-06-01 UTC 2020-02-01 UTC--2020-08-30 UTC
```

As a list it becomes

```
as.list(interval(recessions$Peak, recessions$Trough))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1913-01-01 UTC--1914-12-01 UTC
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1918-08-01 UTC--1919-03-01 UTC
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1920-01-01 UTC--1921-07-01 UTC
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 1923-05-01 UTC--1924-07-01 UTC
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 1926-10-01 UTC--1927-11-01 UTC
#
#[[6]]
#[1] 1929-08-01 UTC--1933-03-01 UTC
#
#[[7]]
#[1] 1937-05-01 UTC--1938-06-01 UTC
#
#[[8]]
#[1] 1945-02-01 UTC--1945-10-01 UTC
#
#[[9]]
#[1] 1948-11-01 UTC--1949-10-01 UTC
#
#[[10]]
#[1] 1953-07-01 UTC--1954-05-01 UTC
#
#[[11]]
#[1] 1957-08-01 UTC--1958-04-01 UTC
#
#[[12]]
#[1] 1960-04-01 UTC--1961-02-01 UTC
#
#[[13]]
#[1] 1969-12-01 UTC--1970-11-01 UTC
#
#[[14]]
#[1] 1973-11-01 UTC--1975-03-01 UTC
#
#[[15]]
#[1] 1980-01-01 UTC--1980-07-01 UTC
#
#[[16]]
#[1] 1981-07-01 UTC--1982-11-01 UTC
#
#[[17]]
#[1] 1990-07-01 UTC--1991-03-01 UTC
#
#[[18]]
#[1] 2001-03-01 UTC--2001-11-01 UTC
#
#[[19]]
#[1] 2007-12-01 UTC--2009-06-01 UTC
#
#[[20]]
#[1] 2020-02-01 UTC--2020-08-30 UTC
```

And there are 522 `TRUE` values in the return value that follows:

```
in_recess <- time(aapl) %within% as.list(interval(recessions$Peak, recessions$Trough))
sum(in_recess)
#[1] 522
```

Comment: For some reason I get this error `Error in time(NFCI) %within% list(as.list(interval(recessions$Peak, recessions$Trough))) : When second argument to %within% is a list it must contain interval objects only`

Comment: @MichaelAzer You have `list(as.list(...))`, it's just `as.list(...)`.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I had list() written twice. I tried encapsulating it with list(), but I get the same initial answer. The problem is that the list I get is not correct if you manually inspect it, and I still get the same warning about object length.

Comment: @MichaelAzer I cannot reproduce the error, see if the edit helps.

Comment: Your answer was right the whole time, I just manually tested it incorrectly. I truly apologize, and thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

As Rui stated, the "as.list" should solve your question. The code is:

```
library(lubridate)
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('NFCI', src = 'FRED')
time(NFCI) %within% as.list(interval(recessions$Peak,recessions$Trough))
```

If you want to move the dummy to NFCI, you can do:

```
NFCI$isRecession <- time(NFCI) %within% as.list(interval(recessions$Peak,recessions$Trough))
```

**Appendix:** The full code I wrote to reproduce your data. It's running ok.

```
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)


peak = c(-20819, -18781, -18263, -17047, 
         -15798, -14763, -11933, -9100, -7731, -6028, -4536, -3562, -31, 
         1400, 3652, 4199, 7486, 11382, 13848, 18293)

trough = c(-20120, -18569, -17716, -16620, -15402, 
           -13455, -11537, -8858, -7397, -5724, -4293, -3256, 304, 1885, 
           3834, 4687, 7729, 11627, 14396, 18504)


recessions <- data.frame(Peak=as.Date(peak),
                         Trough=as.Date(trough)
) 



getSymbols('NFCI', src = 'FRED')
time(NFCI) %within% as.list(interval(recessions$Peak,recessions$Trough))

NFCI$isRecession <- time(NFCI) %within% as.list(interval(recessions$Peak,recessions$Trough))
```

Comment: This is exactly what my code looks like, but I'm not getting correct results if you check it.

Comment: You don't have the "as.list" before "interval". Have you tried to copy and paste my code to run?

Comment: thank you!! It worked, I had a mistake while testing it!